# Starting web development with Perl Dancer2

Tags: perl, dancer

I start with the typical 'Hello word':
(i'm using Fedora 30 )

(file name Web.pl)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Dancer2;

get '/' => sub {
   "Hello World!"
};

dance;
```

then I execute in the terminal:

```
$ perl Web.pl
```

it gives me this:

```
Dancer2 v0.300000 server 12191 listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

then I try:

```
$ curl http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

and it gives me this answer:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 3000: Connection refused
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you doing it in the same terminal? The program needs to keep running. You have to use a different terminal for your `curl`, or use a browser.

Comment: Thanks, you solve my problem

Comment: What if i want to make a web page with Dancer2, do i need to be constaly running the script?

Comment: Yes, you need to be running the script. The software the script is using is running a small web server, and presenting what you have to the browser.

Comment: I don't think you can connect to `0.0.0.0`. When you create a server listening to `0.0.0.0`, it means the server listens to every interface. But I think you still need to use the IP address of one of the interfaces to connect to the server (e.g. `127.0.0.1`)

Comment: Can you please tell me examples of this types of servers?

Comment: There was a new Dancer2 release today. The tutorial has been massively revamped. You might want to take a look. :)

Answer (score 2):

As @simbabque suggested, you need to keep the app running in the original terminal and open another one to call the same end-point. The process, thus the server, stops when you try to use the same one.

Comment: isn't there any server that let you run your script in their server so i don't have to run it in my computer thus been the web page a desing almost always online?

Comment: @Alex Gomez, Yes, such services exist. Recommendations for hosting services are outside the scope of SO.

Comment: There are some tips for this in https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer2/lib/Dancer2/Manual/Deployment.pod. It's not a complete list, but it's a good starting point. The development deployment you are using now is **not** fit for production.